# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Bicycles's [third moderator election](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Criggie]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6551320850857984/0).

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations @Criggie - and now that I have seen your avatar at that size I am even happier (penguins are always good!)

Welcome to the madhouse that is moderation!

Answer (score 4):

Congrats Criggie!

Criggie's consistent presence and good nature will make a great addition to the moderator team. Overall a very good development for the community.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats Criggie! And we look forward to you becoming the highest rep'd user on bicycles.se in the near future!